# How to install add ons of firefox using selenium web driver in cucumber test cases

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have to write script where I need to install firefox-add-on named is "aqqin". how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium with ruby code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = true
    #profile.add_extension "/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}"
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :firefox, :profile => "default"} )
        #Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :firefox, :profile => profile} )
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add addons by creating a custom profile and passing it to the driver.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
File extension = new File("<path>"/aqqin.xpi");
profile.addExtension(extension);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Not `FireFoxProfile` but `FirefoxProfile`

Comment: @Chaki_Black Thanks. Edited the answer.